# Coldfusion.exe v/s Java.exe

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

Has anyone experienced or can someone explain the circumstances wherein the following occurs (and ideally help in resolving it):

What normally happens:

- We execute a large user query/build report process
- Java.exe memory steadily climbs as does CPU usage
- Report Renders, Java.exe CPU utilization drops back down

What, I assume, should not be happening:

- We execute a large user report query/build report process
- ColdFusion.exe memory steadily climbs as does CPU usage
- Java.exe memory and CPU usage do not budge

I should note I do not believe that ColdFusion.exe existed, or at least wasn't present in the computer processes., prior to this behavior. Basically instead of the server running off of Java.exe it's running off ColdFusion.exe. My only theory is that ColdFusion can't find the default java.

Thanks in advance.

**Additional Details**

Server is, and has been, running on ColdFusion 11 Standard
I, foolishly and absent mindlessly, hit the 'Update' button without taking a snap-shot.  Unfortunately, I believe it was patching CF and updating to the most recent version of Java.  CF would not restart so used Adobes Un-install and removed the patches.  It restarted and decided to run the update at a later date. 
My nightly backups had rolled off of the server, by a day, when I realized the server was running so slowly and that Coldfusion.exe was running instead of Java.exe so a simple restore is off the table.

The thing is, the server is running pretty well but not as well as it was.  Additionally, I can not access the debug information by enabling it in the admin and adding my ip.  I can access an error with a cftry and catch but the debug info gives me this and **only** this:

```
Debugging Information 
ColdFusion Server Standard 11,0,07,296330 
Template  /FBI/witsec/locations/map/index.cfm 
Time Stamp  31-Jan-16 01:47 PM 
Locale  English (US) 
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko 
Remote IP  10.14.7.128 
Host Name  10.14.7.128 
------
Execution Time
```

It should be noted the the Execution Time is included in the above snippet, but obviously nothing follows.

Environment Settings - User:
[image: Java Runtime Environment Settings - User]

Environment Settings - System:
[image: Java Environment Settings - System]

**Java and JVM CF 11 Admin Page**

Java Virtual Machine Path:

```
C:\ColdFusion11\jre
```

Minimum JVM Heap Size: `4096`  Maximum JVM Heap Size: `4096`

JVM Arguments:

```
-Xdebug 
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=49325 
-server 
-XX:NewRatio=3 
-XX:SurvivorRatio=7 
-XX:+UseCompressedOops 
-Xss768k 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m 
-XX:PermSize=128m 
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC 
-XX:+UseParNewGC 
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly 
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled 
-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark 
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=68 
-Dcoldfusion.home={application.home} 
-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog 
-Duser.language=en 
-Dcoldfusion.rootDir={application.home} 
-Dcoldfusion.libPath={application.home}/lib 
-Dorg.apache.coyote.USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER=true 
-Dcoldfusion.jsafe.defaultalgo=FIPS186Random 
-javaagent:C:/FusionReactor/instance/ColdFusionOnSGI/fusionreactor.jar=name=ColdFusionOnSGI,address=8088
```

Comment: From memory CF9 (so probably CFMX6-CF8 too) ran in a process called "java.exe", but CF10-11 run in a process called "coldfusion.exe". Is that what you're talking about? You've upgraded and the process names have changed? Your question seems a bit incoherent (or I'm thick, one of the two).

Comment: Do you have any information on the JVM settings?

Comment: Is this idle curiousity or it there a problem you are looking to solve?  Also, I believe CF9 runs in a process called jrun.exe, not java.exe.

Comment: Greetings- I've added some additional details.  Unfortunately, this is a problem I need solved. :(

Comment: Adam-CF 11 normally runs on the Java.exe process.  It's possible that my server has been incorrectly configured for the last number of years but that would just be odd.  It is obviously capable of running on the coldfusion.exe process, so I could be wrong.  But it is not running as well/efficiently, and there are various other quirks.